# Py2exe Directory Structure

Tags: python, py2exe

I use Py2exe to package a Python application with quite a few dependant packages. While Py2exe works flawlessly the resulting dist/ folder with the executable contains a large number (10-15) of support files (.dll, .pyd, .zip).

Ideally I would like to be able to place all of these dependant files in a folder called support/ or lib/ or something to that effect. This way when people download the application and extract the archive they are only presented with an executable and some folders.

Does Py2exe support placing dependant files in a sub-folder? If so, how can one accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An effective solution is to bundle everything in an standalone executable using

`bundle_files:1`

in your setup.py py2exe options.